# Scope of google map variables and functions

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm experimenting with Google maps and am trying to put some polyLines up on the fly. Basically, within the body of the document, I have a setInterval function which will periodically put up lines for a certain time and then erase them after an elapsed duration. The problem comes with accessing the various map variables, but when I try and invoke the test programme (below), I get errors like "marker1 not defined". Is it possible to access the map variables from outside the map initialisation routine?

Here is the Javascript code - this is all within the head

```
var commsLine = [];
var marker1, marker2, marker3, map, Comms;

function initMap() {
    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.8917,-1.3989);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    scaleControl: true
    });

    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.8917, 0),
    map: map
    });

    marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.8917, -1.5),
    map: map
    });

    marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, 0),
    map: map
    });

// DrawLine(); works when placed here but I want to call it from the
// setInterval function in the body
}

function DrawLine()
{

   commsLine.push( marker1.getPosition() );
   commsLine.push( marker2.getPosition() );

      Comms = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: commsLine,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
     });

     Comms.setMap(map);
   }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

Comment: when is DrawLine called? ( initMaps may not be called yet...)

Comment: It should be called in the javascript block in the body.

Comment: Anything that triggers `drawLine()` shouldn't happen till `initMap()` has been called.  What does your other javascript block look like?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think youve got a race problem:

```
 var marker 1;//var init
 drawLine();//draw line called, marker isnt set yet
 initMap(); //map ready
```

Solution 1:
Lock drawLine() until initMap is finished

```
var mapready=false;
function initMap(){
//your code
mapready=true;
}
function drawLine(){
if(!mapready){return false;}
//your code
}
```

This is a good solution if drawLine can be caused by the user.

Solution 2a:
call drawLine when the map is inited:

```
function initMap(){
 //your code
 drawLine();
 }
```

Solution 2b:
Solution a isnt good if you want to call drawLine dynamically (sometimes,sometimes not).
Than it would be good to register callbacks:

```
mapready=[];
function initMap(){
//your init code




//map is ready so call callbacks
for(i=0;i<mapready.length;i++){
 mapready[i]();
}
//if an callback is added now, fire it directly
mapready={};
mapready.push=function(func){func();};
}
```

To add a callback:

```
mapready.push(drawLine);
```

Comment: Thank you - it turned out to be a race condition. I put a test setTimeout call to DrawLine() 3 seconds after the page loads to allow the map initialisation to complete and the line was drawn.
This also solves other problems I am having but it looks like I need to refactor what I have. 

Would your solution 2 fire callback function(s) as soon as the map init completes? It sounds just like what I need but I am not very familiar with callbacks.

Comment: Yep it behaves how you think it would. The callbacks are fired (drawLine in the example) when the mapinit completed or if its added later it is fired right now